# Argument Groups help output

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I'm trying to figure out a solution using the Argparse module.  The help output and my code is below.  The code appears to work.

However, the help output not optimal.  I'd like to communicate via "Usage:" that "-E" requires at at a minimum -s DATE, and that both -s and -e are parameters that only have meaning when used with -E.   (I know I can do that in the text of the help message, but I'm looking for something more obvious for the user.)  I tried out subparser, which seemed to make things a bit clearer.  However, I could not figure out a way to make subparser take arguments without a switch.  For example, my subparser version forced me to enter "SO_Test.py file -f somefile.txt" as opposed to the code below which allows "SO_Test.py -f somefile.txt".   What are my options for better formatted help?

Regards,
Burzin

```
usage: SO_Test.py [-h] [-i | -f FILE | -E ENDPOINT] [-a] [-x] [-s DATE]
                  [-e DATE]

This is my test ArgParse script.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help   show this help message and exit
  -i           Run the script interactively. This is the default mode if n
               options are specfied.
  -f FILE      Run the script against an input file.
  -E ENDPOINT  Run the script against a specific endpoint.
  -a           Audit only.
  -x           Switches queries to use staging.
  -s DATE      Specify a start date. This is mandatory with the -E switch.
  -e DATE      Specify an end date. This optional with the -E switch.
```

---

```
import argparse
from time import time as timer
import sys
def valid_date(iso8601):
    pass
def valid_file(parser, fname):
    pass
    return fname
def file_mode(fname, audit, staging):
    print("Start in file mode.  Audit is {} and staging is {}.".format(audit, staging))
    sys.exit(0)
def endpoint_mode(endpoint, start_time, end_time, audit, staging):
    print("Start in endpoint mode.  Audit is {} and staging is {}.".format(audit, staging))
    sys.exit(0)
def interactive_mode(audit, staging):
    print("Start in interactive mode.  Audit is {} and staging is {}.".format(audit, staging))
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="This is my test ArgParse script.")
    group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
    group.add_argument("-i", \
                        dest="interactive", \
                        action="store_true", \
                        help="Run the script interactively.  This is the default " + \
                             "mode if no options are specfied.")
    group.add_argument("-f", \
                        dest="fname", \
                        help="Run the script against an input file.", \
                        metavar="FILE", \
                        type=lambda x: valid_file(parser, x))
    group.add_argument("-E", \
                        dest="endpoint",
                        help="Run the script against a specific endpoint.",
                        metavar="ENDPOINT")
    parser.add_argument("-a", \
                        dest="audit", \
                        action="store_true", \
                        help="Audit only.")
    parser.add_argument("-x", \
                        dest="staging", \
                        action="store_true", \
                        help="Switches queries to use staging.")
    parser.add_argument("-s", \
                        dest="start_time", \
                        help="Specify a start date.  This is mandatory with the -E switch.", \
                        metavar="DATE",
                        type=valid_date)
    parser.add_argument("-e", \
                        dest="end_time", \
                        help="Specify an end date.  This optional with the -E switch.", \
                        metavar="DATE")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    audit = args.audit
    staging = args.staging
    interactive = args.interactive
    fname = args.fname
    endpoint = args.endpoint
    start_time = args.start_time
    end_time = args.end_time
    if not len(sys.argv) > 1:
        interactive_mode(audit, staging)
    if args.interactive is True:
        interactive_mode(audit, staging)
    if '-f' in sys.argv:
        file_mode(fname, audit, staging)
    if '-E' in sys.argv:
        endpoint_mode(endpoint, start_time, end_time, audit, staging)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: `argparse` does not implement that kind of 'mutual inclusion' grouping.  It's simplest to do that kind of test after parsing (I would use `endpoint is not None` instead of `'-E' in sys.argv`).  And write your own `usage`.  Question - what would be a meaningful `usage` in your case?  I don't understand your requirements well enough to speculate.

Answer (score 0):

With subparsers your `file` case would change from

```
"SO_Test.py -f somefile.txt".
```

to

```
"SO_Test.py file somefile.txt".
```

where the `file` subparser takes one positional argument.

Similarly an `endpoint` subparser could be defined to require a `endpoint` positional, a `sdate` positional (or required optional), and an flagged `edate`.

---

I don't think you need to look at `sys.argv` directly.  There's enough information in `args`. Arguments that aren't given have default values, usually `None`.

```
args = parser.parse_args()
audit = args.audit     # True/False
staging = args.staging     # True/False
interactive = args.interactive    # True/False
fname = args.fname
endpoint = args.endpoint
start_time = args.start_time
end_time = args.end_time

# so if there's any commands do this?
if not len(sys.argv) > 1:
    interactive_mode(audit, staging)

# if args.interactive:
if args.interactive is True:
    interactive_mode(audit, staging)

# if fname is not None:
if '-f' in sys.argv:
    file_mode(fname, audit, staging)

# if endpoint is None:
if '-E' in sys.argv:
    endpoint_mode(endpoint, start_time, end_time, audit, staging)
```

Comment: I'm still struggling with this.  Can you point me to examples where the file subparser takes one positional argument.  Can you also point me to how I can set a default action for a suparser that takes no arguements.  Lastly, I'm trying to do something like this "endpoint_parser.add_argument("-s", dest="start_time", action="store_true", help="The start time", metavar="DATE",
                        type=valid_date)'   However, the use of metavar and type throws errors

Comment: `store_true` takes no arguments.  If present the `dest` is `True`, default `False`.  `metavar` and `type` have no value or use, and might produce errors if given (parameter checking in `arg_arguments` is not strict).

Comment: `sp = parser.add_subparsers(dest='cmd')` will put the name of the subparser in `args.cmd`.  That way you can identify which 'command' was used.